# Installing NumPy with pip3 Fails, but installing with pip is ok

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, pip

I need to install TensorFlow with pip3, when it gets to the installing NumPy step it stops and gives me the error:
(When I tried to install NumPy with pip it was fine, but I need it to work with python 3.)
Thanks in advance for any help.

````
    Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                          
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>                                                                      
      File "/tmp/pip-build-v32qiaml/numpy/setup.py", line 68                                                    
        f"NumPy {VERSION} may not yet support Python "                                                          
                                                     ^                                                          
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax                                                                                 

    ----------------------------------------                                                                    
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-v32qiaml/numpy/```
````

Comment: Never use any of the `pip`, `pip3`, etc. scripts. Instead always use the surefire way of calling the _pip_ module for a specific Python interpreter: `path/to/pythonX.Y -m pip install ...`. -- https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/

Comment: Thank you @sinoroc good advice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[F-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) were added to Python at version 3.6. It seems your `pip3` runs under earlier Python, perhaps 3.5.

Check your `pip` and `pip3` (and their interpreters) versions with `pip --version` and `pip3 --version`. Install more recent Python version if needed.

Comment: Thank you, it seems that python version was 3.5. I have updated it now.